# Adjust tabPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could you please help me adjust the two `tabPanel` that I inserted in my code below? I inserted two and none of them are showing, I don't know what I'm wrong with. Every help is welcome. Thanks in advance. I inserted a executable code below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
        Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,0),
         DR01 = c(4,1,0), DR02= c(4,2,0),DR03= c(9,5,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,4,0),DR06 = c(5,4,0),DR07 = c(5,4,0),DR08 = c(5,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  
  return(df1)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("First Panel",
                                   fluidPage(
                                     fluidRow(
                                       br(), br(),
                                       
                              column(4, "",
                                     wellPanel(
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode")
                                     ),
                                     wellPanel(
                                       conditionalPanel(
                                         condition = "output.mycode",
                                         actionButton("reset", "Reset")               
                                       )
                                     )
                              ),
                              
                              column(8, "",
                                     tabsetPanel(
                                       tabPanel("Output1", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600"),
                                        tabPanel("Output2",uiOutput('daterange')),
                                        tabPanel("Output3")
                                       )
                                     )
                              ))
                          )
  )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2",
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              value = NA,
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  

  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    tagList(dateRangeInput("daterange1", "",
                           start = min(data()$date),
                           end   = max(data()$date),
                           min   = min(data()$date),
                           max   = max(data()$date),
                           format = "dd-mm-yyyy"))
  })         
    
   

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    my$plot <- NULL
    updateDateInput(session, 'date2', value = NA)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'code', h4("Category"),choices= unique(df1$Category), selected=character(0))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not completely certain of what you are looking for or what your problem is, but  I think your "Output2" and "Output3" tab panels aren't displaying, correct? If so, just wrap both of them with a tabsetPanel: ```tabstPanel(tabPanel("Output2",uiOutput('daterange')),
                                        tabPanel("Output3"))```

Comment: Incorrect closure of brackets.  Try `tabsetPanel(tabPanel(...), tabPanel(...))` - as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
column(8, "",
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Output1", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")),
    tabPanel("Output2",uiOutput('daterange')),
    tabPanel("Output3")
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the feedback from @Silentdevildoll would support your needs. Plus your have called fluidPage() two times and navbarPage() within the UI. Additionally, you have assigned the object "ui" twice

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
         Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
         Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
         DR1 = c(4,1,0),
         DR01 = c(4,1,0), DR02= c(4,2,0),DR03= c(9,5,0),
         DR04 = c(5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,4,0),DR06 = c(5,4,0),DR07 = c(5,4,0),DR08 = c(5,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  
  return(df1)
}


ui <-
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel(title = "First Panel",
                             fluidRow(
                               br(), 
                               br(),
                               column(width = 4, "",
                                      wellPanel(
                                        uiOutput("date"),
                                        uiOutput("mycode")
                                      ), #close wellPanel
                                      wellPanel(
                                        conditionalPanel(
                                          condition = "output.mycode",
                                          actionButton("reset", "Reset")
                                        ) #close conditionalPanel
                                      ) #close wellPanel
                               ), #close column
                               column(width = 8, "",
                                      tabsetPanel(
                                        tabPanel("Output1",
                                                 plotOutput("graph", width = "100%", height = "600"),
                                                 tabsetPanel(
                                                   tabPanel("Output2",
                                                            uiOutput('daterange')),
                                                   tabPanel("Output3")
                                                 ) # close tabsetPanel
                                        ) #close tabPanel
                                      ) # close tabsetPanel
                               ) #close column
                             ) #close fluidRow
                    ) #close tabPanel
  ) #close NavPage


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2",
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              value = NA,
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    tagList(dateRangeInput("daterange1", "",
                           start = min(data()$date),
                           end   = max(data()$date),
                           min   = min(data()$date),
                           max   = max(data()$date),
                           format = "dd-mm-yyyy"))
  })         
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    my$plot <- NULL
    updateDateInput(session, 'date2', value = NA)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'code', h4("Category"),choices= unique(df1$Category), selected=character(0))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I would like Output 2 and Output 3 on the Output 1 side if possible. I inserted an example above to you see